# How to use COUNTIF and TAKE function in Excel

Tags: excel, filter, countif, take

I'm new here.

I have a problem with an Excel function.

As the result of take(filter(...)) in Excel I have this list:

[image: Image 1]

So, I want to apply COUNTIF there like: COUNTIF(TAKE(FILTER(..))>74). But when I've tried to do this, Excel show me this:

[image: Image 2]

Does anyone know how to combine these function to have the result that I want (Excel counts how many cells have values greater than 74).

I want to combine countif, take and filter function in Excel.

Comment: COUNTIF will not accept a dynamic array as a range.  It must be a range.

Comment: You cannot use `TAKE()` or `FILTER()` function with `COUNTIF()` as the said function works with a range, unless you are using a `LAMBDA()` helper functions

Answer (score 0):

Well having established that Countif doesn't work with arrays let's have a look at some alternatives. Let's assume that your base formula is something like:

```
=TAKE(FILTER(A1:A100,A1:A100<100),30)
```

(1) Count + Filter:

```
=LET(arr,TAKE(FILTER(A1:A100,A1:A100<100),30),COUNT(FILTER(arr,arr>74)))
```

Straightforward but a bit long. I have used Let to avoid repeating the whole of the base formula.

(2) Take reciprocal of condition and count non-error cells:

```
=COUNT(1/(TAKE(FILTER(A1:A100,A1:A100<100),30)>74))
```

OK but a bit hacky maybe.

(3) The one you will see most often - use Sum instead of Count:

```
=SUM(--(TAKE(FILTER(A1:A100,A1:A100<100),30)>74))
```

where the -- is necessary to convert true/false to 1/0.

(4) Use a lambda

```
=REDUCE(0,TAKE(FILTER(A1:A100,A1:A100<100),30),LAMBDA(a,c,a+(c>74)))
```

Also fine, maybe a bit verbose.

I might add timings to these at some future point but probably they will all be similar and most people would just use the third one, Sum(--arr).

[image]